# Matlab GUIDE: how to deal with multiple overlapping panels

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, panels

I am implementing a sequential procedure, like a sort of "wizards", with Matlab GUIDE where the user should be able to navigate through different panels by pushing the "Next" and "Back" buttons.

Which is the best way to deal with it? I was thinking about overlapping panels I can set to "Visible = on/off" through buttons callback but I don't know if it's possible to do it with GUIDE and, in case, how to do it.

Thanks for your help.

Marco

Comment: Why not use `uitabgroup` and `uitab`? Also you could use `struct2handle` and design each panel separately (http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/handle2struct-struct2handle-and-matlab-8)

Comment: @88mdil please read the tag excerpts for what you're adding to your question. I changed your [guide] to [matlab-guide].

Comment: Sorry @AndrasDeak, thanks for editing my tags.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Suever, I think I am going to implement the second solution you provided, it seems it fits my needs.